# Eigenvalues of a sparse 8x8 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sparse-matrices

I  have the following  $ 8 \times 8 $ sparse matrix

$
P=\begin{bmatrix}
0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 &  0.0\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

I know that $1$ is an eigenvalue because the rows sum to 1 and also that $0$ is an eigenvalue because the matrix is singular( $rank(P)= 4$ so its multiplicity is at least 4).

I'm need to show that there are no other eigenvalues beside $1$ and $0$. Is there any simple way to show that beside using brute force and calculate the eigenvalues directly ?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using Mathematica
\begin{align*}
\mathtt{P=\{\{1/2,1/2,0,0,0,0,0,0\},\{0,0,1/2,1/2,0,0,0,0\},\\
\{0,0,0,0,1/2,1/2,0,0\},\{0,0,0,0,0,0,1/2,1/2\},\\
\{1/2,1/2,0,0,0,0,0,0\},\{0,0,1/2,1/2,0,0,0,0\},\\
\{0,0,0,0,1/2,1/2,0,0\},\{0,0,0,0,0,0,1/2,1/2\}\}}
\end{align*}

$\mathtt{Eigenvalues[P]}$

$$\mathtt{\{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\}}$$

Comment: This does not really help the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Since $P^3=\frac18ee^T$, $1$ is a simple eigenvalue of $P$ and $0$ is an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $7$.

Comment: Yes $ P^3 = 1/8  e e^T $ but how do you get to this ?

Comment: @Tomer Since its nullity is $4$, if $P$ indeed has only $0$ and $1$ as its eigenvalues, the multiplicities of the zero eigenvalue can be determined by the ranks of $P,P^2,P^3$ and $P^4$. It turns out that $P^3$ is nice and useful enough.

Comment: But I can't assume that $P$ has only $0$ and $1$ as its eigenvalues - I need to show it.